# Sahi scripts are not running through Putty

Tags: linux, ssh, putty, sahi

I started Sahi using putty but I got the following error during running scripts:
Script didn't start 150 ms.

I ran both Sahi and script through putty. It's a point to note that running through Linux terminal it's working fine. Please help me regarding this issue.

Comment: i found solution to run sahi using putty in a terminal , for that i used below command
DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm -hold -e "sh /path/to/sahi/bin/sahi.sh"

Comment: but while running same command in remote host i am facing
"cannot open display" error message please help me in this issue

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check if there's any difference between the environments (`env`) when running in a terminal and when running in Putty. Also, if those sahi scripts are bash, you can run it with bash -x to see what's going on inside.

Comment: both enviroments are same ,sahi scripts are not bash

Comment: i found solution to run sahi using putty in a terminal , for that i used below command DISPLAY=:0.0 xterm -hold -e "sh /path/to/sahi/bin/sahi.sh"

but while running same command in remote host i am facing "cannot open display" error message please help me in this issue

Comment: if you want to run an xterm in Putty you need to enable the X forwarding option and to run an X server on the machine on which you run Putty (e.g. http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/)